# T-pose Mode, Automatic Weights

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

[image]

[image]

When I'm in pose mode trying to make my character stand in a T-Pose I get his hips or ribs to come out like batman's wingsuit and I don't know why. I am able to rotate my bones, it moves the arm but randomly sticking out.

I don't know if you guys understand but the hips come out or the ribs. I set the weight of all of the character Blue.
Now I don't know if I should make the character's weight all blue, but someone in a video told me to do it and I don't like what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Timaroberts do you know what i can do?